# Has patent EP2111747A3 been granted?

Tags: application, legal-status

In reference to the patent: [EP2111747A3](https://www.google.com/patents/EP2111747A3)

Answer (score 1):

This is the list of examination ("prosecution") events for this EPO application:
https://register.epo.org/application?number=EP09010216&lng=en&tab=doclist

As you can see, there has been a rejection, and a failed appeal which was dismissed:
https://register.epo.org/application?documentId=E1PXMFAK9711DSU&number=EP09010216&lng=en&npl=false

The application was closed on 20.04.2018.
Although the applicant can attempt to revive it in the coming months and years, this application is most likely dead and buried.

Comment: "Although the applicant can attempt to revive it in the coming months and years" Only by means of reeinstatement for two months after the loss of rights communication or after noticing if the loss of rights didn't reach the attorney which is improbable. So its very very very probably dead.

Answer (score 0):

At least in the US it has: [US8859846](https://www.google.com/patents/US8859846).

Answer (score 0):

Not granted, [examination is in progress](https://register.epo.org/application?number=EP09010216).

Comment: see @EricShain 's answer regarding granting of the U.S. counterpart.